# Organizing Code Into Classes?

Tags: java, class, coding-style

I code plugins for the popular Bukkit API for Minecraft.

Basically, at this point, my coding is just one class with a ton of methods and public variables. How can I neatly organize this code into classes?

In coding terms, how would I go about doing this? Would I import each class?

I noticed when accessing variables from another class, I have to do: ClassName.variable every time, and that's a bit of a drag. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Program to interfaces. No, really. Then make each interface say what it does -- it should do ONE thing -- and then compose the interfaces into concrete types (classes). Just getting down the separation into a documented interface goes a good way to showing HOW it can be divided. I swear sub-typing exists in Java only as a means of "implementation sharing" :(

Comment: If you even have to ask this, I don't think you understood what OOP means: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no fan of Java, but this problem isn't about being a Java n00b.  It's about being new to object-oriented design (you'd run into this problem with large programs in any language if you organize them well).

You'll generally want to follow the ["Single Responsibility Principle"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  In a nutshell, it means that your classes should probably be smaller than they are now, and that each of them should be in charge of handling a small enough task that it's easy to tell whether it's correct.  This is easier said than done, but that's why programming is hard: organizing your ideas is hard.

Comment: Same way you'd implement it in Notepad.  But more seriously, Eclipse has tools for adding new classes and I believe it has refactoring stuff.  I'm afraid you'll have to figure that stuff out for yourself.  The basic idea is to figure out where each class is managing 2+ things that could be reasonably managed by separate classes, and then separating them.

Answer (score 0):

Break the code down into classes, each of which contains *related* data and methods that describe the behaviour of that data. There will usually be lots of alternative designs; it's a matter of experience.  Try to create classes that make sense in your domain, i.e. that are modelling real-world things (this isn't always possible or sensible, just a rule of thumb).

Answer (score 0):

> In coding terms, how would I go about doing this?

Identify which methods implement functionality which belongs together. And refactor them into classes.

> Would I import each class?

Your IDE (eclipse or whatever) will do the imports for you.

> I noticed when accessing variables from another class, I have to do:
>   ClassName.variable every time, and that's a bit of a drag. Is there a
>   way around this?

First you wrote ClassName instead of instance, (This implies static)
In Java you have the option to do a static import

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

after that you could use the symbols in more natural way like:

```
double r = cos(PI);
```

instead of

```
double r = Math.cos(Math.PI);
```

But to be honest, I wouldn't recommend this in general.